# Repeating Simple Text

Tags: macros

Is there an easy way to repeat a simple piece of text?  For example, I want to write `$\downarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & ...` (for a table).  I tried `*{8}{$\downarrow$ &}`, but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could define a command, say `\rpt` that repeats some command a number of times. Here I've defined `\rpt[<repeat>]{<stuff>}` that repeats `<stuff>` `<repeat>` number of times. `<repeat>` is an optional parameter, that defaults to `1` if not used:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forloop}% http://ctan.org/pkg/forloop
\newcounter{loopcntr}
\newcommand{\rpt}[2][1]{%
  \forloop{loopcntr}{0}{\value{loopcntr}<#1}{#2}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{*{8}{c}}
  \rpt[7]{$\downarrow$&} \unskip$\downarrow$ \\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

It is a very elementary example, but shows how you can shorten your code to repeat something over and over. Looping is provided by [`forloop`](http://ctan.org/pkg/forloop) which implements a "nested iteration", and is easy to use for small repetitive stuff.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks!  What does `\unskip` do in the 4th-to-last line of your code?

Comment: @jamaicanworm: You'll notice that if you remove it, the spacing of the last column is not correct; left over from the last use iteration of `\rpt`. That space is removed using `\unskip`.