# Remove page number from backside of custom title page

Tags: header-footer, titles, memoir, page-numbering, emptypage

In the following document, I am using `\titleGM` for a custom title page, from the [`titlepages`](https://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/info/latex-samples/TitlePages/titlepages.pdf) collection. This results in a page number (in Roman numerals) on the backside of the title page. However, if I replace the custom `\titleGM` with `\maketitle`, then there is no page number on the backside.

Note that page numbering correctly restarts from *i* for the Table of Contents even with the custom title page.

How do I remove the page numbering from the backside of the custom title page?

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\input{titleGM.tex}

\usepackage{blindtext}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37396/2113
% Just to have a long enough ToC to see its page numbers
\usepackage{forloop}
\newcounter{loopcntr}
\newcommand{\rpt}[2][1]{%
  \forloop{loopcntr}{0}{\value{loopcntr}<#1}{#2}%
}

\title{Retrocomputing with Clash}
\author{Gergő Érdi}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\begin{titlingpage}
\titleGM
%% \maketitle
\end{titlingpage}

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\rpt[30]{\chapter{Foo}\Blindtext}

\backmatter
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using this slightly modified version of `titleGM`

It will suppress a blank page before the title page and remove the page numbering up to the table of contents.

**titleGM** source from [titlepages.pdf (page #53)](https://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/info/latex-samples/TitlePages/titlepages.pdf)

[image: a]

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{blindtext}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37396/2113
% Just to have a long enough ToC to see its page numbers
\usepackage{forloop}
\newcounter{loopcntr}
\newcommand{\rpt}[2][1]{%
    \forloop{loopcntr}{0}{\value{loopcntr}<#1}{#2}%
}

\title{Retrocomputing with Clash}
\author{Gergő Érdi}
\date{}

\newcommand*{\titleGM}{%
\pagestyle{empty}  % added <<<<<<<<<<<<
\newlength{\drop}
\setlength{\drop}{0.1\textheight}
\begingroup% Gentle Madness
    %   \vspace*{\baselineskip} % commented <<<<<<<<<<<<
    \vfill
    \hbox{%
        \hspace*{0.2\textwidth}%
        \rule{1pt}{\textheight}
        \hspace*{0.05\textwidth}%
            \parbox[b]{0.75\textwidth}
                {\vbox{%
                    \vspace{\drop}
                    {\noindent\HUGE\bfseries Some\\ [0.5\baselineskip]
                        Conundrums}\\[2\baselineskip]
                    {\Large\itshape Puzzles for the Mind}\\[4\baselineskip]
                    {\Large THE AUTHOR}\par
                    \vspace{0.5\textheight}
                    {\noindent The Publisher}\\[\baselineskip]
                }% end of vbox
            }%   end of parbox
        }%    end of hbox
    \vfill
    \null       
\endgroup
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{titlingpage}
        \titleGM
        %% \maketitle
    \end{titlingpage}

    \frontmatter
    \tableofcontents
    
    \mainmatter
    
    \rpt[30]{\chapter{Foo}\Blindtext}
    
    \backmatter
```